# What to do if some fields are not put by user in form submission?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, webforms

I have a webform in `ASP.NET` this form includes almost 40 fields from which some are picture upload fields.

If some fields are not related to user he/she will not put any value in them so how can I handle this if some values are not insert by user in form. So that its doesn't through an error due to empty fields.

Comment: The fields must not be required and the corresponding database field should be able to accept null

Comment: This is up to you, it is part of your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't to do with program logic as much as it is business logic so you *could* do this:

When a user does not input any data into a field you could:

1) Allow your database table(s) to accept null values for when this case occurs and treat the data that you use in future as though it may contain nulls.

2) Populate any fields that the user did not enter any information in with 'dummy data'. This is to say that you could do something like:

```
string someForm = "";
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(txtSomeForm.Text))
{
    someForm = "N/A";
}
```

Then you check within your program for whether the string that was input by the user, and saved to the database equals "N/A" (non-applicable). If it equals "N/A" then you know it's not relevant to the user.